# How can I check/compare float?

Tags: unity, c#

The full script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Spin")]
    public bool spin = false;
    public Vector3 Direction;
    [Range(0, 300)]
    public float speed = 10f;
    public bool randomSpeed = false;
    public bool randomDirection = false;
    [Range(0f, 100f)]
    public float timeDirChange;
    public Vector3 defaultDirection;

    [Space(5)]

    [Header("Move in circles")]
    public bool moveInCircles = true;
    public GameObject rotateAroundTarget;
    public Vector3 axis;//by which axis it will rotate. x,y or z.
    public float rotationSpeed; //or the speed of rotation.
    public float upperLimit, lowerLimit, delay;// upperLimit & lowerLimit: heighest & lowest height;
    public bool randomHeight = false;
    public bool stopRotatingWhenFacing = false;
    private float height, prevHeight, time;//height:height it is trying to reach(randomly generated); prevHeight:stores last value of height;delay in radomness;


    [Space(5)]

    [Header("Follow objects")]
    public GameObject[] objectsToFollow;
    public bool randomFollow;

    private float nextRotationTime = 0f;
    private int counter = 0;
    private List<GameObject> Soldiers = new List<GameObject>();

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        Soldiers.AddRange(GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Soldier"));
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (randomSpeed)
        {
            speed = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 300);
        }

        if (spin)
        {
            if (randomDirection == false)
            {
                nextRotationTime = 0;
                timeDirChange = 0;
                Direction = defaultDirection;
            }
            else
            {
                if (Time.time > nextRotationTime)
                {
                    nextRotationTime += timeDirChange;
                    RandomDirection();
                }
            }

            transform.Rotate(Direction, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else
        {
            timeDirChange = 0;
            randomDirection = false;
            randomSpeed = false;
        }

        if (moveInCircles)
        {
            MoveInCircles();
        }
    }

    private void RandomDirection()
    {
        Direction = new Vector3(UnityEngine.Random.Range(-1, 1), UnityEngine.Random.Range(-1, 1), UnityEngine.Random.Range(-1, 1));
        while (Direction == new Vector3(0, 0, 0))
        {
            counter++;
            Direction = new Vector3(UnityEngine.Random.Range(-1, 1), UnityEngine.Random.Range(-1, 1), UnityEngine.Random.Range(-1, 1));

            if (counter == 2)
            {
                Direction = new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
                break;
            }
        }

        counter = 0;
    }

    private void MoveInCircles()
    {
        var F = GetAverageDirectionsOfSoliders();
        var D = transform.position - GetAverageLocationOfSoliders();
        var angle = Vector3.Angle(D, F);

        if (angle <= 5f)
        {
            rotationSpeed -= 0.1f;
        }

        transform.RotateAround(GetAverageLocationOfSoliders(), axis, rotationSpeed);
        //transform.RotateAround(rotateAroundTarget.transform.position, axis, rotationSpeed);
        time += Time.deltaTime;
        //Sets value of 'height' randomly within 'upperLimit' & 'lowerLimit' after delay 
        if (time > delay)
        {
            prevHeight = height;
            if (randomHeight)
            {
                height = UnityEngine.Random.Range(lowerLimit, upperLimit);
            }
            time = 0;
        }

        if (randomHeight == false)
        {
            height = transform.position.y;
        }

        if (randomHeight)
        {
            //Mathf.Lerp changes height from 'prevHeight' to 'height' gradually (smooth transition)  
            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, Mathf.Lerp(prevHeight, height, time), transform.position.z);
        }
        else
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, height, transform.position.z);
        }
    }

    private Vector3 GetAverageLocationOfSoliders()
    {
        var total = new Vector3();

        foreach (var soldier in Soldiers)
        {
            total += soldier.transform.position;
        }

        return total / Soldiers.Count();    // Assuming Soldiers is List<Soldier>
    }

    private Vector3 GetAverageDirectionsOfSoliders()
    {
        var totalf = new Vector3();

        foreach (var soldier in Soldiers)
        {
            totalf += soldier.transform.forward;
        }

        return totalf / Soldiers.Count();
    }
}
```

This is the part where I try to compare the floats to slow down the transform rotationSpeed (In this case the transform is a camera).

```
private void Update()
{
    var F = GetAverageDirectionsOfSoliders();
            var D = transform.position - GetAverageLocationOfSoliders();
            var angle = Vector3.Angle(D, F);

            if (angle <= 5f)
            {
                rotationSpeed -= 0.1f;
            }
}
```

I see that angle is 86.33425342 then 83.456456 but it's never get inside the

```
if (angle <= 5f)
```

Never get to the line

```
rotationSpeed -= 0.1f;
```

I want to slow down the speed once the angle is lower then 5 or any other threshold value. In this case I set it to 5.

Comment: It looks like you're checking/comparing the float just fine. It's just that the number you're working with never gets into the range that you're checking for. We don't have a lot of context to guess at why that is, or how you should change your formula or your movement logic to bring it into that range. You might want to edit your question to include more background information about what feature you're trying to implement.

Comment: @DMGregory I found that this condition is working: if (angle < 30f && rotationSpeed > 0.1f) The angle is never getting low then about 17. I used a break point to find it out. But if I was not using a break point how should I make the check then ? The idea what I want to do is when the camera(transform) is facing the soldiers(objects) then slow down and stay facing them without rotating around them again.

Comment: @BenziAvrumi maybe there is some always present vertical angle? Either way `Debug.Log` and `UI.Text.text` are your best friends.

Comment: I didn't read all that, but based on your title, see https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Approximately.html.